# Why did Mace Windu and the Jedi Council refuse to raise Anakin to the rank of Master?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

I don't really understand why the Jedi Council did this, other than because they think that Anakin is Palpatine's agent. But surely Anakin is right; how can he be on the Council and not be a Master?

If it's because they think he's too cocky, why didn't they bounce him years ago, since four high-ranking Jedi Masters said they felt a disturbance of dark Force energy surrounding Anakin?

Comment: Because he's woefully underqualified for the job?

Comment: Then why did they let he  joined the council?

Comment: Because the Chancellor appointed him

Comment: Anger management issues. He apparently tried to choke a coworker. Oh, wait...

Comment: "other than because they think that that Anakin is Palpatine's agent." ***'Nuff said!***

Comment: @Machavity Only because the coworker was exhibiting religious intolerance. Quit trying to take away his right to practice his religion as he wishes! You lefties and your War on Sithmas!

Comment: @Acccumulation, well said!!

Comment: He was way too good for them. He should simply have left them gracefully when he realized this.

Comment: @nccs_0x: to borrow from Elizabeth I of England: "Keep your friends close, and your enemies closer".

Comment: @Accumulation: WRONG! The guy had a lisp and said that Anakin was a weak sister!

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica, but the council did not have an enemy in Anakim, they created one!!!

Answer (score 73, accepted):

### Why can't Anakin be a Master?

Anakin's appointment was political, not spiritual. Historically the Jedi elected their own leaders by consulting the will of the Force and by mutual consent. Anakin, on the other hand, was appointed directly by Palpatine as his 'envoy' to the Council, and his appointment pushed through by Palpatine's allies in the Senate.

In short, the Jedi don't think he's ready. He's far too young, hot-headed and well, *arrogant*, to be part of their elite.

> “Then we should use someone else’s eyes,” Obi-Wan said “Forgive me,
>   Master Yoda, but you just don’t know him the way I do. None of you
>   does. He is fiercely loyal, and there is not a gram of deception in
>   him. You’ve all seen it; it’s one of the arguments that some of you,
>   here in this room, have used against elevating him to Master: he lacks
>   true Jedi reserve, that’s what you’ve said. And by that we all mean
>   that he wears his emotions like a HoloNet banner.
>
> <sub><sup>[Revenge of the Sith: Official Novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Episode_III_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(novelization))</sup></sub>

On top of all of that, they really don't trust him. They think his loyalties are divided between the Jedi and the Chancellor.

> “Listen to me, Anakin,” Obi-Wan said, and the seriousness of his tone caught Anakin’s attention. “The fact is, you’re too close to the Chancellor, and the Council doesn’t like him interfering in Jedi affairs.”
>
> <sub><sup>[Revenge of the Sith: Junior Novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(junior_novelization))</sup></sub>

There's also the fact that the rank of Master gives you access to certain artefacts such as holocrons and the deeper teachings of the Jedi. In the wrong hands, those would be spectacularly dangerous.

> All that mattered was Mastery.
>   All that mattered was Padme.
>
> This was a gift beyond gifts: as a Master, he could access those forbidden holocrons in the restricted vault. He could find a way to save her from his dream …
>
> <sub><sup>[Revenge of the Sith: Official Novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Episode_III_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(novelization))</sup></sub>

---

### So why did they agree to have him on the Council at all?

His appointment was a done deal. They weren't consulted on this, they were simply informed that Anakin had been made a Council member. It's not a hill that they're willing to die on, so they have to wear it. On top of that, having him on the Council means that Palpatine will consult with him more than ever before, which gives the Jedi an opportunity to have Anakin spy on the Chancellor for them and to feed him misinformation.

> Obi-Wan stopped walking and turned to face Anakin. He hesitated, as if
>   he was searching for the right words. Then he took a deep breath. “The
>   Council wants you to report on all of the Chancellor’s dealings. They
>   want to know what he’s up to.”
>
> Anakin stared at Obi-Wan, stunned. A tiny part of his mind whispered,
>   Don’t ever ask Obi-Wan to come right out and say something, ever
>   again, but most of him was trying to absorb what Obi-Wan had just
>   said. “They want me to spy on the Chancellor?”
>
> Obi-Wan nodded.
>
> <sub><sup>[Revenge of the Sith: Junior Novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(junior_novelization))</sup></sub>

Comment: But then, what bad it was that he wanted to save his mother and Padme? , to avoid the holocrons and the deep jedi learns.

Comment: @riccs_0x - Jedi are supposed to divorce themselves from personal emotions that might cloud their judgement.

Comment: even with that in account, saving his mother and Padme could be seen as any other thing a jedi would do, I think the council went wrong , since there was the high chance the dark side corrupted Anakin, why not embrace he more  instead of relegate?

Comment: >Taking the Return of the Jedi Luke  cares about his father and is able to jump into anger without being overcome, so speaking of the jedi step away of personal emotions.

Comment: @riccs_0x - The Council made many many mistakes that eventually led to their destruction. Failing to communicate effectively with Anakin was one and allowing him to carry on with a Senator was another.

Comment: @riccs_0x - Luke's feelings for his friends nearly drive him into the arms of the Emperor.

Comment: @riccs_0x " saving his mother and Padme could be seen as any other thing a jedi would do" yes, but not at all costs like Anakin does.

Also regarding Luke: he was treading a fine lint

Comment: @riccs_0x iirc (and not sure if still canon) this was the point, the Jedi had become rigid and dogmatic. There's little wisdom in telling an 8 year old to not love his mom, or a 16 year old to not like a girl. I think the new Jedi order that Luke founded addressed this, but it's been a while so I might be mistaken.

Comment: @riccs_0x You'll also remember the whole debate in Phantom Menace how Anakin as a small boy is way too old to start the training because of family. Jedi aren't supposed to have girlfriends either.

Comment: @riccs_0x There's the slight issue of Anakin indiscriminately murdering innocent parties as revenge for the death of his mother to consider.

Comment: In regards to "_So why did they agree to have him on the Council at all?_", it might be worth quoting what Palpatine said on the matter to help show how Palpatine was pulling all the strings "_Anakin, this afternoon the Senate is going to call on me to take direct control of the Jedi Council. ... They will report to me . . . personally._" / "_Anakin . . . I'm appointing you to be my personal representative on the Jedi Council._"

Comment: @JohnB In other words, Anakin is there as a *proxy* for the Supreme Chancellor, not as a member in his own right.  And that proxy need not always be a Jedi, either, so awarding them the rank of Jedi Master would be a bad precedent.

Comment: @Chronocidal, why didnt write it as an aswer>>? I think ist well explained and enought compact to not lost detail and avoid to be so cumbersome.

Comment: Like Yoda said, there is anger in him, which leads to darkness. That was the reason. Basically Yoda feared for what happened; Anakin lost control of himself (although I doubt he predicted Anakin would become a sith)

Comment: @paddotk, then why did the council let Anakin joined and received the train (whatever the train is), they should have tried to protect or try to guide him instead of blast him, like in the scene.

Comment: @riccs_0x For one, he was already being trained since childhood. Also, he *was* being guided by Obi-Wan. The rank of Master, however, gets one great power and responsibility and the council felt Anakin wasn't reliable enough for it.

Comment: @paddotk, but it speaks of how awkward and fool the council was, I dont remember that Anakim, by himself, wanted to be a jedi, it was Qui-gon, under council orders, that enticed Anakim to become a knight, the council later kick him and denied what it was trained for, using him almost as a failed product that can be disposable.

Comment: @riccs_0x He wasn't revoked of his role as Jedi, just denied the position of Master. Basically he didn't make the promotion.

Answer (score 34):

Watch the video again and you'll see why. Jedi believe in emotionless serenity; they don't let their emotions cloud their judgment. Anakin was a powerful Jedi but he was still far too passionate and emotional. A prime example of this was his reaction to being denied the rank of master, yelling at the council for not promoting you is surely not an example of setting aside your emotions and being reasonable instead. It was extremely childish.

He clearly wasn't mature enough to be a master and the council clearly must have known this.

Comment: The Jedi aren't against emotion per se. They're against attachment. You're allowed to love your fellow sentients and you're allowed to hate injustice. What you aren't allowed to do is love your wife and hate your enemies.

Comment: @Valorum It seems to be kind of inconsistent. In KOTOR they taught 'there is no emotion; there is peace' and 'there is no passion; there is serenity'.  My idea might be that they have always been against attachment and that for a long time they taught against emotion as it lead to attachment but between KOTOR and the films they drifted away from that teaching (see 'new Jedi code'). Either way, Anakin's outburst was immature and a Jedi Master surely wouldn't behave that way.

Comment: Anakin gives us a nice rundown here; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bOcH-tBgFCY - "*Attachment is forbidden. Possession is forbidden. Compassion, which I would define as unconditional love, is essential to a Jedi's life. So you might say, that we are encouraged to love.*"

Comment: @Valorum Yeah I had that in mind while writing that, I'm not sure that compassion really counts as an emotion though.

Comment: Compassion is an *act* that could stem from either emotional attachment or rational belief in a being's right to receive compassionate treatment. Anakin is looking for a loophole, not stating an objective fact.

Comment: @chepner Perhaps. But "unconditional love" is still the kind of thing that totally makes sense. His problem isn't looking for technical loopholes, it's that his love is _anything_ but unconditional.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Anakin is a very good Padawan but he never took the trials like Obi-Wan did so therefor Anakin can't be a Master. And even if Anakin was a Master the Council picks its own members.

Comment: "_the Council picks its own members_" - not in this case. Palpatine took control of the Jedi Council, the Senate voted to have them report directly to him. He made the unanimous decision to put Anakin on the council.